# SQL query with both table columns-Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables named, for an example A and B.

A and B has a unique column named key_ref. and key_ref is the primary key of both tables

I need to find records in A but not in B. Therefore I wrote a query like,

```
SELECT a.*,b* from A a,B b WHERE key_ref NOT IN (SELECT key_ref from B)
```

The issue with this is, I do not get the empty columns of table B for the result. My result should include all the columns of A and B.

If I write my query like following my results get wrong. Is there any way , where I can achieve this even with a join condition.

```
SELECT a.* from A a WHERE key_ref NOT IN (SELECT key_ref from B)
```

Please refer following example.

```
Table A                            Table B

key ref  col1                   key ref  col2

 A        aaa                    A        aaa
 B        bbb                    B        bbb
 C        ccc                    C        ccc
 D        ddd
```

My answer should be,

```
key ref  col1   col2

D        ddd
```

Comment: What brand of database?

Comment: Please add your DBMS

Comment: HI its Oracle database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your request:

You can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` operation so you'll get all rows in A not present in B (with condition in `WHERE b.key_ref IS NULL`)

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN b
ON a.key_ref = b.key_ref
WHERE b.key_ref IS NULL
```

Comment: Hi Joe, Key ref is the primary key of both tables. Actually I need to find records in A , where it do not has a reference key as same as B. But the output result should include the columns of both tables A and B

Comment: Does something appear incorrect in the results? From your description, this query should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you need:

```
select * from A
except
select * from B
```

?

Answer (score 1):

*If* the second table *tableB* doesn't have a record associated with first table, then how would you display record from second table *tableB* which are not exists in the first table *tableA*.

So, the one way is to include `NULL` as columns ref. to *tableB* like that :

```
select a.*, null col2
from tableA a
where not exists (select 1 from tableB b where b.key_ref = a.key_ref);
```